# Android: support %s expansion in DialogPreference summary

Tags: java, android, string, android-preferences, dialog-preference

first question.  long time searcher.

i implemented a timePicker preference through expansion of DialogPreference as in the android docs.  all works well and i can set the summary through onSharedPreferenceChanged() and also in the override of DialogPreference onSetInitialValue().

my goal is to always have the summary shown *with* its value and some other strings from resources.
for instance in my ListPreference i have:

```
android:summary="@string/pref_list_camera_summary"
```

which resolves to:

```
<string name="pref_list_camera_summary">Use camera: %s</string>
```

in my timePreference %s doesn't get expanded.  i've searched around and i can't figure out how to get the dialogPreference/timePreference to do this.
i *can* set the summary manually in onSetInitalValue() like this:

```
setSummary(getSummary() + " " + DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext()).format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis())));
```

i just don't like implied expansion like that.  doesn't feel as clean or use the android %s paradigm.

i'll start digging through the listPreference code and see how i can add this to dialogPreference.   any ideas/head-starts would be great!

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace the preferred string with `%s` defined in `android:summary` automatically, I think there is no such possibility. You should handle it programmatically in initialization of your preference. Have you tried to use `String.format()` to avoid `+` concatenation?

```
String date = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext())
        .format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

setSummary(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), 
        getContext().getString(R.string.pref_list_camera_summary), date));
```

Comment: The problem is that `getSummary()` is not called in the first place. If you can somehow tweak the derived preference class to make sure it gets called you could indeed use the `string.format()` trick.

Comment: If you want to initialize the summary in the preference activity/fragment, it is a common practice to do it in onResume method. Another way is to do the initialization tasks in `onBindViewHolder` of your custom preference class. It is feasible to call `getSummary()` method there.

Comment: In my case, the binding is **null** when `onBindViewHolder(PreferenceViewHolder holder)` method is called from the preference overview. Hence, there is no way to get hold of the value that should replace the `%s` container.

Comment: Not sure what to share. Given that the summary is set to `%s` it is desirable for a derived `DialogPreference` to **override** `getSummary()` and format the text accordingly. The first problem is that `getSummary()` is not even called. Obviously, the derived class needs some logic which I assume somebody out there has implemented since 2014. Hence the bounty :)

Comment: I have created a custom `DialogPreference` and override the `getSummary()` method. It is called correctly and shows the overriding summary in preferences. You can share summary-related parts of your custom preference class.

Answer (score 3):

If you use library [Material Preference](https://github.com/anggrayudi/MaterialPreference), you can do it easily:

```
listPreference.summaryFormatter = { entry, value -> "Value for $entry is $value" }
```

It will set your `ListPreference`'s summary to something like **Value for Weekly is 7**.

I know that this answer is not strongly related to your question. But at least, you have found a library that can do it. With Material Preference, you don't have to set `%s` to the `ListPreference`'s summary.

Comment: It's a `DialogPreference` :/